# UIStackView height is not 0 when arranged subviews' heights are all zero

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, view

I suppose the height of a vertical UIStackView should be the total height of its arranged views. However, when I change the frame height of all arranged views to 0, the frame height of the UIStackView is still having a non-zero value even `view.layoutIfNeeded()` is called and all the arranged views are disappeared. I have also tried to set the `Clip to Bounds` of the UIStackView to true but it stills does not work. Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  print("Before --- UIStackView.frame.height: \(stackView.frame.height)")
  print("Before --- firstLabel.frame.height: \(firstLabel.frame.height)")
  print("Before --- secondLabel.frame.height: \(secondLabel.frame.height)")
  print("Before --- thirdLabel.frame.height: \(thirdLabel.frame.height)")
  print("Before --- forthLabel.frame.height: \(forthLabel.frame.height)")
  for view in stackView.arrangedSubviews {
    view.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.origin.x, y: view.frame.origin.y, width: view.frame.width, height: 0)
  }
  print("===================================")
  print("After --- UIStackView.frame.height: \(stackView.frame.height)")
  print("After --- firstLabel.frame.height: \(firstLabel.frame.height)")
  print("After --- secondLabel.frame.height: \(secondLabel.frame.height)")
  print("After --- thirdLabel.frame.height: \(thirdLabel.frame.height)")
  print("After --- forthLabel.frame.height: \(forthLabel.frame.height)")
  view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Here is the log:

```
Before --- UIStackView.frame.height: 82.0
Before --- firstLabel.frame.height: 20.5
Before --- secondLabel.frame.height: 20.5
Before --- thirdLabel.frame.height: 20.5
Before --- forthLabel.frame.height: 20.5
 ===================================
After --- UIStackView.frame.height: 82.0
After --- firstLabel.frame.height: 0.0
After --- secondLabel.frame.height: 0.0
After --- thirdLabel.frame.height: 0.0
After --- forthLabel.frame.height: 0.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using a mixture of auto layout and setting frames manually. To see that everything works as expected instead of setting the labels' frames to a height of 0 set their `text` property to an empty string (which results in an `intrinsicContentSize` with a height of 0):

```
// Your print statements BEFORE...

for arrangedSubview in stackView.arrangedSubviews {
    if let label = arrangedSubview as? UILabel {
        label.text = ""
    }
}
view.layoutIfNeeded()

// Your print statements AFTER...
```

Results in:

[image: result]

Answer (score 4):

With stack views you can simply hide subviews to adjust its height.

```
for view in stackView.arrangedSubviews {
    view.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the total height and change the view height.

```html
let total = stackView.arrangedSubviews.reduce(0) { result, view in 
return result + view.frame.height
}
```